# Mockito mock object returns cumulative result in second test method

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, springrunner

I am using mockito to mock a JpaRepository class that returns a list of **Object[]**. The mocking is as follow:

```
@MockBean
private UtilisateurSuiviRepository utilisateurSuiviRepository;
```

So I'm using this mock object o test diffrent scenarios and return different results.

In the first test method I have this:

```
    when(utilisateurSuiviRepository
            .findUtilisateursInactifsPourPremiereRelance(10))
            .thenReturn(new ArrayList<Object[]>(){{
                add(new Object[]{8L, Instant.now()});
            }});
```

In the second test method I have the same thing but with different parameter and return result:

```
when(utilisateurSuiviRepository
        .findUtilisateursInactifsPourPremiereRelance(16))
        .thenReturn(new ArrayList<Object[]>(){{
            add(new Object[]{5L,null});
        }});
```

The problem is that depending on the execution order of the methods, my second method remember also the return result of the first mock, so it returns two lists :

```
new Object[]{8L, Instant.now() // <-- first list of array object
new Object[]{5L,null} //<-- second list of array object
```

Expecting result is:

```
new Object[]{5L,null} //<-- what should I get in the second method
```

I'am aware that mockito keeps the same state for all mocks, so I did this to init the mocks before each test method:

```
    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
```

But it does not change anything and I keep getting the same issue.

Note that I'm using SpringRunner to run my test class in a context of spring batch:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@MyCustomBatchUnitTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.batch.job.names=myJob"})
```

The definition of MyCustomBatchUnitTest is as follow:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@SpringBootTest(classes = { CommonsConfiguration.class })
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles({CommonsConfiguration.PROFILE_BATCH, CommonsConfiguration.PROFILE_TEST, CommonsConfiguration.PROFILE_BATCHTEST})
public @interface MyCustomBatchUnitTest{
    
}
```

I tried also to init the mock manually **inside each method** as follow:

```
utilisateurSuiviRepository = mock(UtilisateurSuiviRepository.class); 
when(utilisateurSuiviRepository
                .findUtilisateursInactifsPourPremiereRelance(16))
                .thenReturn(new ArrayList<Object[]>(){{
                    add(new Object[]{8L, Instant.now()});}});
```

But in that case the mock method that is just after is not being processed.

Bellow a github link that produce the same problem:
https://github.com/MrPenguina/mockito_issue/blob/main/JobTest.java

Comment: Your question and explanation of your code is confusing. Also I wouldn't use a new arraylist and add stuff, instead use `List.of(new Object[] {8, Instant.now()}` etc. to create a new unmutatble list. The `@RunWith` is, normally, useless as that is for JUnit4 **not** JUnit5 which (according to your tags) is what you are using. If you are mixing JUnit4 and JUnit5 in a single test things will go wrong.

Comment: Firstly, having mocks calling/returning other mocks is not great and can lead to weird scenarios such as this one.  I would try to change the design of the test and avoid this if possible. Alternatively, you can try `Mockito.reset(utilisateurSuiviRepository);` in the @BeforeEach block and this should successfully reset the mock

Comment: @M.Deinum the List.of was introduced in java 9, I'm using java 8

Comment: Then use `Collections.singletonList` or `Arrays.asList` instead. The mocks will be reset between tests (if properly used, which judging from the small snippets here, I doubt). Please add the full test including imports etc.

Comment: And you haven't shown any code where a "mock is being called by another mock".

Comment: @EmanuelTrandafir I tried `@BeforeEach` but is not being called, I used  `@Before` instead and it is working, I did try to Mockito.reset even for both mocks and it's not working..always the same problemm.

Comment: @M.Deinum I did change the return type as you suggested using Collections.singletonList, but nothing changed

Comment: The fact that `@BeforeEach` isn't working and `@Before` is it looks as if you are mixing both JUnit4 and JUnit5 in a single test. Don't as that will lead to weird issues. Make sure you are either only using `org.junit` classes or only `org.junit.jupiter.api` class. I suspect you are mixing both leading to the mock not being reset. As requested before please add your full testclass **including the imports**!.

Comment: @M.Deinum I did verify the imports, and I'm only using the org.junit package. I updated the question as you requested for

Comment: @tgdavies I excuse, the other mock is not calling my first mock, it was an error from my part, actually bot mocks are called separately when my test batch starts

Comment: Write a small test class which reproduces this behaviour and post the entire class.

Comment: Please ad dthe **whole test class** not just snippets. We ask for that information for a reason. If you are using JUnit4 why have you marked it for JUnit5?

Comment: the link toward the test class was added in the question @M.Deinum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by the guys in the comments, I had to use:

```
Mockito.reset(utilisateurSuiviRepository);
```

Because `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks` method is used within `@Mock` of Mockito framework and not for `@MockBean` of spring framework.

Also note that in the context of Spring Batch, I had a final `List` that I initialize in the declaration, the list is used to hold the result of my `JpaRepository` by calling the method `addAll` inside the `beforeStep` method, which was causing the issue in my case and kept giving me a cumulative result:

```
private  final List<Object[]> listeUtilisateurSuiviInactif = new ArrayList<>();
```

I had to move the initialization of this list inside the `beforeStep()` of the reader so like that the list will be initialized each time whenever a test method is called.

In conclusion, I had to correct the mistake above and to use `Mockito.reset` method inside the `@Before` method.

### UPDATE

Other alternative to keep the list intitialization in the declaration instead is to use the annotation `@DirtiesContext` withing the test class:

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
```